# get date from firebase format change

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

earlier we push date use native Firebase format

```
createAt:admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date)
```

1. so data store like this

```
 "createAt": {
            "_seconds": 1563181560,
            "_nanoseconds": 567000000
        }
```

2. new we change like this

```
createAt:new Date().toISOString()
```

now store like this 
`"createAt": "2019-07-17T07:17:05.115Z"`

buts some date store like this because  we use native date format

now how can i call old date to new date format?  moste of the data sote like native date method is that any way to change new method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firestore [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) type has many conversion methods. Just like it has a `fromDate()` it also has a `toDate()` method. So if you reload the data from Firestore and get a Timestamp object, you can then get a date with `timestamp.toDate()` and thus an ISO-8859 formatted string with `timestamp.toDate().toISOString()`.